# Control Flexbox column width using content on different rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve a table-like structure using Flexbox, because tables are really difficult to control in the context I'm trying to put them in and it's known that `tr` doesn't play nice with animations and some CSS stylings and is pretty incosistent across multiple browsers and devices.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/68Lc86sg/

What I'm trying to do is make the last two columns the same width across all the rows, like in the table example. Is there a way to achieve this using flexbox?

Comment: you could apply a `min-width` to your `li`

Comment: display:flex or table are 2 different ways, purposes, behaviors http://jsfiddle.net/68Lc86sg/1/

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is not the most appropiate way to do this, because it has no grid concept.

However, you can (more or less) achieve it by placing all the grid cells in the same flex container, reorder them, and use a column layout.

```css
dl {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  height: 4em;
}
dt, dd {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 0;
  flex: 0 1 50%;
  min-height: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
dt { order: 1; }
dt + dd { order: 2;}
dt + dd + dd { order: 3; }
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Hotel 25</dt>
    <dd>0 stars</dd>
    <dd>0 ratings</dd>
  <dt>Hotel 2254</dt>
    <dd>1222 stars</dd>
    <dd>124 ratings</dd>
</dl>
```